# Is it possible to customize the newsfeed application on sharepoint? e.g. font size, uploaded image size's

Tags: intranet

Hi I want to be able to customize the newsfeed app on SharePoint.

I want to be able to increase the font size of the posts and make any attached images larger.

Regards,
David

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to change certain elements (such as Font size) with CSS and / or Javascript, but not everything (Images have a maximum size of 300px when they are stored. I'm looking into a solution that addresses this myself!).

These code edits can be made in the "Content Editor Web Part", "Script Editor Web Part", or even in the Master Page.

Please check out the following links

https://blog.josequinto.com/2014/06/09/branding-tip-custom-style-in-newsfeed-and-site-feed-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013/

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/05/adding-javascript-and-css-to-sharepoint.html